# Systemd Login Service not working properly | i3wm

Tags: systemd, manjaro, power-management, suspend, logind

I have a problem with the suspend on lid closure, which is not working anymore together wirh i3wm (with xfce it works).
The systemd login service is running and also detects the lid close and open events but then do not behave as configurated.

Here the systemd status of the service:

```
● systemd-logind.service - User Login Management
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service; static)
 Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-08-23 21:28:29 CEST; 8min ago
   Docs: man:sd-login(3)
         man:systemd-logind.service(8)
         man:logind.conf(5)
         man:org.freedesktop.login1(5)

   Main PID: 8998 (systemd-logind)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 16617)
     Memory: 1.3M
        CPU: 111ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-logind.service
             └─8998 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind

Aug 23 21:28:29 MaxT495 systemd-logind[8998]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
Aug 23 21:28:29 MaxT495 systemd-logind[8998]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
Aug 23 21:28:29 MaxT495 systemd-logind[8998]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event7 (ThinkPad Extra Buttons)
Aug 23 21:28:29 MaxT495 systemd[1]: Started User Login Management.
Aug 23 21:28:29 MaxT495 systemd-logind[8998]: New session 2 of user max.
Aug 23 21:28:33 MaxT495 systemd-logind[8998]: Lid closed.
Aug 23 21:28:41 MaxT495 systemd-logind[8998]: Lid opened.
Aug 23 21:29:06 MaxT495 systemd-logind[8998]: Power key pressed.
Aug 23 21:31:19 MaxT495 systemd-logind[8998]: Lid closed.
Aug 23 21:31:26 MaxT495 systemd-logind[8998]: Lid opened.
```

And here the important part of the logind config file:
Output of `cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf | grep "#" -v`:

```
[Login]
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

So as stated in systemd service status, the lid close event is detected but then my laptop does not suspend! :(

Can someone help me please?

Additional information:
`systemctl suspend` works!

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED". If one of the answers solved your issue, consider accepting it. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

If someone runs in the same issue, execute:

```
$ systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block
```

to check if there is another service which blocks system actions.